# XML data extraction from an API link Python

Tags: python, xml, scrapy, python-requests, xml-parsing

I was trying to scrape an `API URL`. I am getting the response in the `XML` format. I was familiar with `JSON's` response but it's quite new to me. I was wondering how can we go ahead and extract the data from an `XML` response using `Scrapy` or `Request`. What type of expressions are used to target certain values for example `<FirmName>`, `<FirmId>`. **(Please go to the links below for checking the data)**

Link: https://www.ricsfirms.com/umbraco/api/surveyorSearchApi/results?location=United%20Kingdom&firmName=&lon=-5.2235136&lat=50.2307777&boxId=14821&country=GB&page=1

Comment: What exactly is the problem? What have you tried?

Comment: You should look up XML parsing and BeautifulSoup.

Comment: I am not familiar with BS but have knowledge of Request. I want to know how can I target the values in the XML response? Like we can do with XPATH or CSS selector. What's the method for XML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the following as it returns JSON:

```
import requests

r = requests.get('https://www.ricsfirms.com/umbraco/api/surveyorSearchApi/results?location=United%20Kingdom&firmName=&lon=-5.2235136&lat=50.2307777&boxId=14821&country=GB&page=1')

data = r.json()

for office in data['resultOffices']:
    print(office['firmId'])
    print(office['firmName'])
    print('---')
```

Comment: It worked, thanks, Dennis. Can you also tell me how can I target the values like <FirmName>, <FirmId>

Comment: I have expanded my answer. You can use square brackets like in a simple array to get the data you want.

Comment: Be aware that keys are case sensitive and the the searched key does exist. In your case there is no `Email1`